# Apply Angular JS Directive if element is visible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written the below directive to close the `<a>` element on a click outside itself, and I want this directive to start executing if the element is visible; currently it is executing on every click event over the document despite the element is visible or not.

```
app.directive("outsideClick", ['$document','$parse', function( $document, $parse ){
            return {
                link: function( $scope, $element, $attributes ){
                    var scopeExpression = $attributes.outsideClick,
                        onDocumentClick = function(event){
                            var isChild = $element.find(event.target).length > 0;
                            if(!isChild) {
                                    $scope.$apply(scopeExpression);
                            }
                        };

                    $document.on("click", onDocumentClick);

                    $element.on('$destroy', function() {
                        $document.off("click", onDocumentClick);
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Comment: Hi, you can give a shot at angular [InView](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview)

Comment: can you post html code?